# spring security login url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to configure /login to land on my home page on successful authentication.
For example,
"http://localhost:8080/app/login" , land me on my home page, which is
"http://localhost:8080/app/home".
If I click same URL again, it redirects me to http://localhost:8080/app. However, if I do http://localhost:8080/app/logout and then again try to login, its good.

Why does it not redirect me to same home page on trying to login multiple times?

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(staticResources).permitAll().antMatchers("/login*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .failureHandler(authFailureHandler).successHandler(sessionTimeoutAuthSuccessHandler).permitAll().and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler()).deleteCookies(JSESSIONID)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the configuration you have shared, users will be redirected to `"/home"` after authenticating successfully if they have not visited a secured page prior to authenticating.
If they have visited a secured page prior to authenticating, then they will be redirected to that page.
If you wish to always redirect to `"/home"`, then you can set `alwaysUse` to `true`.

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
```